# currency symbol image in ionic

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework

i am trying to get the value of Total redemption to be on the same line with the word "Total Redemption" like the way Total Accrued Points looks, i am using an image for my currency symbol and the code for this display is

```html
<div class="item item-body " >  
  <div class="container">
  <div class="right">
     Total Accrued Points :  {{reportData.accruedpoints}}<br/>
     <p>Total Redemption:<img src='img/naira.gif' alt="Naira" height='20' width='20' align='bottom'> {{reportData.redeemableamt | currency : ""}}
    </p>
    </div>
    <a  <a href="#/app/transactionsBreakDown/{{reportData.submerchantId}}" class="button button-full button-assertive ink" >View {{reportData.submerchantId}} Details</a>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Could you share the part of your CSS that contains the classes you use in your code? That would make it much easier to come up with a solution.

Comment: thanks i already got a solution for this, there is a html representation for the naira symbol which i got as &#8358; from http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20a6/index.htm